# How to add Asp.net templates for Visual C# 2008 Express

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have Visual C# 2008 Express and I want to create an application for the web.  From my research online, I've read that I need Asp.Net, but these templates aren't available.  I found a MS download, but it is for both and I don't want o uninstall what I already have.  What is the proper way to add this into what I already have?

Comment: It appears that it's no longer available on Microsoft's servers, but you would have needed to download the web developer edition along side the C# edition. Is there a reason you need to continue using 2008 vs. 2010 or even better 2012?

Comment: It is my understanding that 2008 Express is the only one that works with the arcobjects(GIS) interface.  That is the only reason I'm with 2008.  Can I just download the web developer edition by itself?

Comment: See this http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2008/05/06/missing-templates-in-visual-studio-installed-templates/